# Bokeh ResetTool expected behavior

Tags: python, bokeh, bokehjs

What is the expected behavior of ResetTool ?

Aside of reseting the plot canvas to its original size, should it also have effect on widgets, for example checkboxes (that is: assuming that on plot creation all checkboxes are set to active, then some of them are deselected, should clicking a reset tool in the toolbar reset them to their original state ?)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Bokeh specifications](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#resettool):

> The reset tool will restore the **plot ranges** to their original values